# How do delete an specific page in a word document using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel VBA to create and populate a word document and I'd like to delete a specific page in that document. I tried the following approach for deleting:

```
With wDoc
    .GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:="20" 'Page number
    .Bookmarks("\Page").Select
    With Selection
      .Delete
    End With
End With
```

This code doesn't return any error message on execution but the word page content isn't deleted as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Check below code. I have removed quotes from name parameter here (replaced "20" with 20)
You can use your document reference wDoc instead of Activedocument that I have used.

```
With ActiveDocument
    .GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=20 'Page number
    .Bookmarks("\Page").Select
    With Selection
      .Delete
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Hi Amol. I got the following error message: "Object doesn't support this property or method". It seems not to work on Excel VBA but works fine when creating macros within MS Word

Comment: @EduardoSantiago If it works in MS Word, but not Excel; I would look more into what type of binding you're using (early or late) and make sure that your code is consistent for the binding-method used. (Early binding will only work on other computers with same builds; late binding does not allow cross-use of defined constants, and does not support intellisense.)

Comment: Hi Mistella, I'm using late binding. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @EduardoSantiago: in that case you have to ensure that `wDoc` refers to an object in MS Word... so it might be `With objWordApp.wDoc ...`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to keep deleting until the page itself is fully gone.

```
Sub DeletePage(iPageNumber As Integer)
'
' DeletePage Macro
'

With ThisDocument
    .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, name:=iPageNumber).Select
    .Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Select
End With

Selection.Delete

' keep deleting until page is gone
Do
    Selection.MoveLeft Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Delete

Loop Until Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) < iPageNumber
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
With wdDoc
    Lr = .Goto(wdGoToPage, wdGoToLast).Start
    .Range(Lr - 1, wdDoc.Range.End).Delete
End with
```

Or

```
wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Goto(wdGoToPage, wdGoToLast).Start - 1, wdDoc.Range.End).Delete
```

It will find the last Character/Rage and Delete